# How to persist a cart through a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently facing an issue trying to create a page with a cart system which would look like this:

**Items part of the page:**

> ```
> Item1 | Some info | Add to cart
> -------------------------------------
> Item2 | Some info | Already added (2)
> -------------------------------------
> Item3 | Some info | Already added (3)
> ```

**Cart part of the page:**

> ```
> Remove from cart | Item2 | Quantity textbox (2) | Item 2 total amount 
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> Remove from cart | Item3 | Quantity textbox (3) | Item 3 total amount
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>                                                   Cart total amount
>
> Purchase
> ```

I don't need the cart to be persisted when the user goes to another page, however I obviously need it to maintain its state between each action (add to cart, remove from cart, and whenever the quantities change).

I found examples but they were all using database (I don't think I need it) or `Session` (I read that using `Session`for those kind of things was not recommended).

The problem is, I guessed the best way to achieve this was by using forms; the "add to cart" form is okay, but there is an issue for "remove from cart" and "purchase" forms because they would need to be nested.
I managed to do something working (can add the code if necessary) but each action refreshes the whole page to maintain both "Items part" and "Cart part" hiddens fields up to date, and a controller action is also called whenever the quantity textbox value changes, to maintain the hidden fields and update total amounts.
I find it really ugly...

What other option do I have ?
Is database a better idea even if I don't need it to be persisted out of the page ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since HTTP is stateless, you need to decide how you are going to maintain state between trips. There are many ways: db, sessions (fine if you are not using a web farm), cookies, file, hidden fields. Read on each one a bit and then go with it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Hi, thanks for your reply. I read some posts saying that using Session in an ASP.net MVC web app was not recommended, espcially in this case where I do not need to persist data for a whole session. Regarding database I'm concerned about performances (and it do not seem very relevant since data does not have to be persisted through pages). I was going to use forms but due to this nested case it would imply to send a request each time the quantity changes, to maintain the whole thing. Does not seems great. I was wondering which way to go in this particular case.

Comment: Actually your data does have to be persisted through pages. Just because you are not showing it to the user does not mean it does not have to be persisted through pages. User goes to the cart page, then some other page and comes back to cart page; some other page did not show the cart but it still needs to be persisted. People write all sort of posts, sessions are fine but in some cases they will not be the ideal choice. Like I said, read about the choices you have and see which is good for you.

Comment: If this was a classic cart system I would actually need to use database (there is plenty of examples about it) but this is not an e-commerce app, the "cart-like system" is at the bottom of the products page will remain excusively there. It will be lost if the user goes to another page because there is no need to persist it further in my particular case. Anyway thanks, I guess I will have to go with database since forms solution is so ugly.

Comment: Ok if you do not need it to keep state once the user visits another page, then just do everything on the browser using javascript. What is the point of going to the server? If you need something from the server use AJAX. If you do not want to use JavaScript, pass everything on your page back and forth between page refreshes. Create a class that has all the fields you need for your page. Use that as the model for you page. Use that model in your page and also in your controller when you are adding/removing stuff from the cart. Yes you do not need a database, session or any of that in this case.